# FIX- Php form submit alert redirects to other page

Tags: php, html

I have written a code for form which on submit opens the demo.php tag in the browser. I want the form to produce a (Thank you) alert on same page without redirecting to demo.php. Is it possible to embed a jquery notificaiton plugin? If yes then how?

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);

define('DB_NAME', 'form');
define('DB_USER', '******');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*******');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('It worked!')</script>";
exit();


$value = $_POST['name'];
$value2 = $_POST['email'];
$value3 = $_POST['bio'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO form (name, email, bio) VALUES ('$value', '$value2','$value3')";

if (!mysql_query($sql))  
{
       die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}


mysql_close();

?>

<form method="post" action="demo.php" id="form"  >      
    
   <center><legend><h1> Enter Your Details </h1></legend>

            <div class="formelement">
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required/>
            </div>
 
            <div class="formelement">
                <label for="email">Email-ID: </label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required/>
            </div>
   
   <div class="formelement">
       <label for="bio">Your Message: </label>
    <textarea rows="1" cols="15" name="bio" id="bio"></textarea>
   </div>
   
   <div class="formelement">
                <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit"/>
            </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Think about mysql vs mysqli. mysql functions are depricated. Also sanitize your input, never trust the input from your users, your code is wide open for injections.

Comment: yes, @Dorvalla is right. google mysqli connections and prepared statements to improve this code. need to get used to it.

Comment: are you using bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
<form method="post" action="demo.php" id="form"  >
```

to

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form"  >
```

it will post form to same file and so do not redirect to other page

and print alert inside-

```
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('It worked!')</script>";
$value = $_POST['name'];
$value2 = $_POST['email'];
$value3 = $_POST['bio'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO form (name, email, bio) VALUES ('$value', '$value2','$value3')";

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

if ($result)  
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('success!')</script>";
}
mysql_close();
```

You can use jquery ajax form submission .so that you can give alert using jquery

[see here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: still not working....its refreshed without giving alert and pushing entries into db

Comment: delete your line exit()